# Drawing a large weighted network in networkx based on thickness?

Tags: networkx, thickness

How do I draw a weighted network of N>1000 nodes in networkx by thickness? If I have a .csv list of source, target nodes and the weight for each edge, and I am thinking of using the method:

```
for i in range(N)
G.add_edge(source[i],target[i], weight=weight[i]) 
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G)
```

but then, do I have to give thickness to every edge? or every group of edges with similar thickness?

Answer (score 14):

You can specify each edge individually, or you can define them in groups if you have some function to compute groupings (and then use multiple calls to `draw_network_edges`).

Here's an example with a random graph that uses the edge weights as is, first to define the edge thickness and second, using the data as coloring instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

n = 15; m = 40

# select some edge destinations
L = np.random.choice(xrange(n), 2*m)
# and suppose that each edge has a weight
weights = 0.5 + 5 * np.random.rand(m)

# create a graph object, add n nodes to it, and the edges
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(xrange(n))
for i, (fr, to) in enumerate(zip(L[1::2], L[::2])):
  G.add_edge(fr, to, weight=weights[i])

# use one of the edge properties to control line thickness
edgewidth = [ d['weight'] for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True)]

# layout
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, iterations=50)
#pos = nx.random_layout(G)

# rendering
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211); plt.axis('off')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=edgewidth,)

plt.subplot(212); plt.axis('off')

# rendering
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color=edgewidth)

plt.show()
```

Which gives you something like this: [image: thickness / coloring of edges]

Clearly you could use a more complicated function to assemble the list of edgewidth values as suitable to your application (e.g. binned values or a product of different properties) as well.

Comment: How about adding a legend?